# How is React state management internally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I wonder how React manages state internally.

To tell you a little bit more, I wonder how the inside of useState() also works so that the state is reactive!

useState(); I know that hooks provide state and state change functions as return values.

```
const [testState, setTestState] = useState('test');
```

I'm curious to see how it works inside React.

Answer (score 0):

useState give you a back array and you can destructure that array the first element is state and the second one is a function that can change state often is called setState and to if the state is reference type you should first clone it and change reference to component re-rendered and if the state is not reference type you cane easily change state with setState without cloning original state

Comment: So, how are those states managed inside react?